# Can't Catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency

I'm trying Catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException

When I debuging, I got entity.RowVersion is not same with productEdit.RowVersion.

But I don't know why this program keep success to save the data.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] ProductEditModel productEdit)
{
    var entity = await this.unitOfWork.Products.GetByIdAsync(id);

    this.mapper.Map(productEdit, entity);

    try
    {
        await this.unitOfWork.SaveAsync();   // <<---  here.
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        return Conflict(ex);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

This is my entity class :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue is described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12492). It's about EF core but I've also tested it for EF6 and it's the same there.

The bottom line is that EF looks at the *original value* of a `RowVersion` property when comparing it to the current database value. This comparison is part of the SQL update command, which contains a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE ...
WHERE [ID] = @p1 AND [RowVersion] = @p2;
```

The `@p2` parameter is the *original* value of the `RowVersion` property. When the versions don't match a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown.

So there's the problem...

```cs
this.mapper.Map(productEdit,entity);
```

...only updates `RowVersion`'s current value.

So *if* you want to manipulate `RowVersion`s value you have to change the original value. And for that you need the entity entry, like so:

```
context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.RowVersion).OriginalValue = rowversion;
```

Since you wrapped the context in a unit of work/repository pattern you'll have to find out how to implement this.

However, you may want to consider a different approach. I think you shouldn't get the `Product` entity from the database and set its values and manipulate its `RowVersion`. It's more appropriate to map `productEdit` to a new `Product` entity object and *attach* that object to the context. This will automatically set the original value of `RowVersion` to the version you want it to have. As bonus, it saves a roundtrip to the database.

Comment: @Arnold,
I want to use your approach, can you give the code<br/>
I tried :<br/>
`var entity = this.mapper.Map<Product>(product);`<br/>
`await this.unitOfWork.Products.InsertAsync(entity);`<br/>
That code give me message : 'Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Products'. The duplicate key value'

Comment: Did you remove the first line `var entity = ...` ?